# Unable to select last button in list of <p>'s using CSS

Tags: html, css

In the below code I want to select last ".button" using CSS. The number of p's are different and so does the .button's. I want to select the last .button in the list of p's.

```
<div class="container">
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text
    <a class="button" href="#">button</>
</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text
    <a class="button" href="#">button</>
</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text</p>
/*can be more p's here*/
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this purely with CSS currently. Are you able to introduce some Javascript?

Comment: @AHaworth yes we can use js as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this purely with CSS.

To do it with Javascript you would probably be best off being as specific as possible so as not to pick up any a elements that may be further buried inside the p elements.

This snippet assumes that the anchor elements you are interested in are the direct children of the p. Of course alter the selector if this changes:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.container > p > a.button');
els[els.length - 1].style.background = 'magenta';
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text
    <a class="button" href="#">button</a>
  </p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text
    <a class="button" href="#">button</a>
  </p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  /*can be more p's here*/
</div>
```

Note: the anchor elements in your question were not correctly terminated. (`</a>` required)

Answer (score 0):

**js:**

```
const last = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.button')
).pop();
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".button:last")
```

Comment: `$(".button:last")` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want access it for styling, you can use the following in CSS:

```
p a:last-child {
      
    }
```

Comment: This would select all anchors that are the last child in a paragraph; not simply the last anchor with the button class

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is Reut answer

You can use

```
p:last-Child
{

}
```

To select the last child of p in this example, so if you want you can replace it with other attributes/classes or id's etc

Notice that this will work using CSS

Comment: Not only is this wrong, you capitalized child.

Comment: I don't think that there is another way or at least a simple way to select the last specified element of the whole code. So he can select the direct parent of the element and then style it as he wants.

Comment: Without JS there isn't. And your answer (if the typo was fixed) would select all paragraphs that are the last child in a parent. It wouldn't select the last anchor with the button class, so I'm not sure why you got an upvote

Answer (score -1):

```
const allBtns = documnet.querySelectorAll('.container .button')
const lastOne = allBtn[allBtn.length-1]
```

Comment: `documnet.querySelectorAll('.container>button')` selects nothing since no button classed element is a child of `.container`